# Using jquery templating with c#'s dynamics?

Tags: c#, jquery, dynamic, jquery-templates

I didn't think this would be that hard, but I am trying to pass a class that has a dynamic for a property (which is currently being set as an expando object in the c#) into the View.  In this view, a good bit is getting rendered w/ some jQuery Templating and I thought that if I had this in the c# code:

```
public dynamic SomeProperty {get;set;}
...
SomeProperty = new ExpandoObject();
SomeProperty.SomeValue = "5";
return View(TheClassThatContainsSomeProperty);
```

Such that in the jquery templating I could do:

```
${SomeProperty.SomeValue}
```

...and that it would hopefully work. It doesn't... If you inspect the response, you can see that it essentially gets sent over as a dictionary:

```
SomeProperty: [{SomeValue, Value:5}]
0: {Key:SomeValue, Value:5}
```

which leads to (I guess) my next question: Is there an easy way to access dictionaries in jquery templating? I did try this:

```
${SomeProperty["SomeValue"]}
```

to no avail either.  At this point the only thing I know to do is to leverage the ability to put a function in the template (as copied here from the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/) website):

Template:

```
<tr><td>${getLanguages(Languages, " - ")}</td></tr>
```

Code:

```
function getLanguages( data, separator ) {
    return data.join( separator );
}
```

So am I over complicating this? Can I easily either 1) access a dynamic value from jquery template or 2) Easily lookup a value from a dictionary in jquery template?

Comment: sidebar: looking at the documentation for the `$.tmpl()` plugin, it appears this plugin is no longer under active development. if you like the jQuery template syntax, you might consider using mustache / mustache.js instead. There's even a library for .NET that would allow you to use server-side templates too. See: http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: yeah, good point... Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandoObject` derives from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>`, and most serializers will recognize a `dynamic` as this type when you assign an `ExpandoObject`. This is why you see an array type on the javascript side with named **Key**::**Value** pairs.

[ExpandoObject Class (System.Dynamic) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

One alternative to using `ExpandoObject` is to use C# anonymous types. When serialized to json, these map field by field as you expect.

[Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

It is possible to access values declared with `dynamic` from jQuery, but most likely you won't be returning a MVC `View()` with the model to be consumed with jQuery, as any server-side view template engine (razor, etc.) can already perform the same template activities with less overhead. Instead, jQuery templates are better used with Ajax calls.

Here are code examples demonstrating three cases where a variable declared `dynamic` on the server is consumed with jQuery templates in the browser.

The first example uses an anonymous type for the member field `SomeValue`, and has a jQuery template that treats it as a member object.

The second example uses an array of anonymous types for the member field `SomeValue` and has a template that uses `{{each}}` syntax to enumerate the items. Note that this is a scenario where things can go badly with `dynamic`, as you get no strongly-typed support and must either know the correct type or discover it at the time you access it.

The third example uses an `ExpandoObject` for the member field `SomeValue`, and has a jQuery template like the first example (single member object). Note that in this case, we need to use a helper function `pivotDictionaryMap()` to pivot **Key**::**Value** pairs into object members.

Starting with a blank C# MVC3 Web Project, we need to modify three files to demonstrate these examples.

Inside **_Layout.cshtml**, add script includes for jQuery templates and a proper version of jQuery in your <head> element.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside **HomeController.cs**, we'll add some methods that return json `ActionResult`s. Also, for brevity we'll just declare a class `SomeModelType` here; and note that a proper application would probably have this class declared in its **Models**.

```
using System.Dynamic; // up top...

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SomeDataSource(int id)
    {
        dynamic d = new { innerId = 99, innerLabel = "inside object" };
        SomeModelType obj = new SomeModelType(id, "new object");
        obj.SomeValue = d;

        return Json(obj, "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult SomeDataSourceWithArray(int id)
    {
        dynamic d1 = new { innerId = 99, innerLabel = "inside object (first array member)" };
        dynamic d2 = new { innerId = 100, innerLabel = "inside object (second array member)" };

        SomeModelType obj = new SomeModelType(id, "new object");
        obj.SomeValue = new object[] {d1, d2};

        return Json(obj, "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult SomeDataSourceWithExpando(int id)
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        d.innerId = 99;
        d.innerLabel = "inside object";

        SomeModelType obj = new SomeModelType(id, "new object");
        obj.SomeValue = d;

        return Json(obj, "text/plain");
    }
}

public class SomeModelType
{
    public SomeModelType(int initId, string initLabel)
    {
        Id = initId;
        Label = initLabel;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public dynamic SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in the default view, we will add script tags for the templates and the javascript necessary to consume them. Note the use of `$.post()` and not `$.get()`, as a `JsonResult` in MVC disallows GET requests by default (you can turn these on with an attribute).

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<script id="someDataTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
Item <b>${Id}</b> is labeled "<i>${Label}</i>" and has an inner item with id <b>${SomeValue.innerId}</b> whose label is "<i>${SomeValue.innerLabel}</i>".
</script>

<h3>SomeDataSource Example #1 (Single Item)</h3>
<div id="someData">
</div>

<script id="someDataArrayTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
Item <b>${Id}</b> is labeled "<i>${Label}</i>" and has these inner items:
<ul>
 {{each SomeValue}}
    <li><b>${innerId}</b> has a label "<i>${innerLabel}</i>".</li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

<h3>SomeDataSource Example #2 (Array)</h3>
<div id="someArrayData">
</div>

<script id="someDataTemplateFromExpandoObject" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
Item <b>${Id}</b> is labeled "<i>${Label}</i>" and has an inner item with id <b>${SomeValue.innerId}</b> whose label is "<i>${SomeValue.innerLabel}</i>".
</script>

<h3>SomeDataSource Example #3 (Single Item, Expando Object)</h3>
<div id="someDataFromExpandoObject">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pivotDictionaryMap(src)
{
    var retval = {};

    $.each(src, function(index, item){
        retval[item.Key] = item.Value;
    });

    return retval;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Ajax Round-Trip to fill example #1
    $.post("/Home/SomeDataSource/5", function(data) {
        $("#someDataTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#someData");
    }, "json");

    // Ajax Round-Trip to fill example #2
    $.post("/Home/SomeDataSourceWithArray/67", function(data) {
        $("#someDataArrayTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#someArrayData");
    }, "json");

    // Ajax Round-Trip to fill example #3
    $.post("/Home/SomeDataSourceWithExpando/33", function(data) {
        data.SomeValue = pivotDictionaryMap(data.SomeValue);
        $("#someDataTemplateFromExpandoObject").tmpl(data).appendTo("#someDataFromExpandoObject");
    }, "json");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark my own answer as "correct" just on premise that I don't like this answer.  If someone figures out what I was trying to do above, I'll gladly give you the points.

```
    function getDisplayValue(data, toMatchOn) {
        var _return = $.grep(data, function (n, i) { return (n.Key == toMatchOn); })[0];

        if (_return != null)
            return _return.Value;

        return "";
    }
```

and in the jquery template:

```
${getDisplayValue(DisplayFields, 'Something')}
```

So I was able to get this to work with the method described above so here it is as a possible solution but I don't know javascript well enough to know how bad of a performance hit this could be creating (and as I research it, I'll update this answer) but I thought javascript dictionaries were optimized against their key value, so the fact that MVC doesn't serialize expando as a true javascript dictionary seems to make this answer very inefficient.  And the fact that I originally took this tack with the dynamic c# object was that I originally thought this would serialize down into a cleaner form.  Anyway, this works but Occam's Razor is just making this feel way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help or not, but have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3042650). It is hard to tell from your code snippets but if you are turning that `ExpandoObject` into JSON, then try wrapping it on a `DynamicJsonObject` first, as done in the gist.

---

Code from the Gist copy/pasted for those who don't want to click the link:

```
// By default, Json.Encode will turn an ExpandoObject into an array of items,
// because internally an ExpandoObject extends IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.
// You can turn it into a non-list JSON string by first wrapping it in a DynamicJsonObject.
[TestMethod]
public void JsonEncodeAnExpandoObjectByWrappingItInADynamicJsonObject()
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    expando.Value = 10;
    expando.Product = "Apples";

    var expandoResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(expando);
    var dictionaryResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(new DynamicJsonObject(expando));

    Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":10,\"Product\":\"Apples\"}", expandoResult); // FAILS (encodes as an array instead)
    Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":10,\"Product\":\"Apples\"}", dictionaryResult); // PASSES
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that performance is going to be sketchy if you're iterating over an array to find a key.  But you should be able to comfortably convert the key-value-pair array (that the server sends back) into a "true" Javascript dictionary/map.  Eg:

```
var kvps = [ {key: "test", value: "expando"}, {key: "hello", value: "world" } ]; 
var map = {};
kvps.forEach(function(kvp) { map[kvp.key] = kvp.value; } );
console.log( JSON.stringify(map) );
```

> {"test":"expando","hello":"world"}

Of course, if you're nested objects, then you'd have to apply recursion to the above approach to make it work.